# How does the core 'php.ini' directive 'memory_limit' is considered as an 'Environment Variable' in an code example from the PHP Manual?

Tags: environment-variables, directive, php-ini, php

I'm using **PHP 7.2.8** on my machine that runs on **Windows 10 64-bit Operating System**.

I come across the following code example from [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php#configuration.file) having some description :

> Using environment variables can be used in **php.ini** as shown below.
>
> **Example #1 php.ini Environment Variables**
>
> ```
> ; PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT is taken from environment
> memory_limit = ${PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT}
> ```

I executed the above code on my machine it gave me the following error messages :

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT - assumed 'PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in demo.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined variable: PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT in demo.php on line 3
```

I checked the list of available **'Environment Variables'** on my machine but I didn't get such environment variable named `$_ENV['PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT']`

Then, I checked the **php.ini** file present on my machine. I found the core **php_directive** `memory_limit=128M`

So, my question is why the code example from PHP Manual is considering something similar(`${PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT}`) to the core **'php.ini'** directive as an **'Environment Variable'**?

Also, the code written in this code example doesn't work as such environment variable named `${PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT}` doesn't exist.

I even checked [the latest](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=php.ini-production;hb=HEAD) **php.ini** from Git as recommended in the PHP Manual but in that file also I found the core **php_directive** `memory_limit=128M` and no environment similar to it.

Is the PHP Manual having wrong code example?

Someone please clear my doubts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that your example is not a code example, it's a configuration example. So it belongs on `php.ini` and not on a PHP file.

Environment variables are system dependent and it is up to you to set them. The manual is giving you an example with the aptly named `PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT`. You could set that variable on your system and then use it on your `php.ini`. But you can call it whatever you want, that's just an example, it's not based on any specific platform where that variable would be set.